# Convert datetime column to datetime2 column in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2005 database with a `datetime` column. There is already data in the table but now the customer needs dates before 1753. So I decided to migrate the database to a SQL Server 2008 to use the `datetime2` type.

However I can't just switch the type of the column from `datetime` to `datetime2`. Is there a way to do this conversion or do I have to reimport the data?

Thank you,

Daniel

Comment: I gotta ask: why do they need dates before 1753?

Comment: It's a database about historic texts and letters..

Comment: Why can't you just change the type? `alter table TableName alter column ColumnName datetime2`?

Comment: @TheQuant - I take it you are aware about the Gregorian calendar issues when dealing with these dates. (If not just thought I'd mention it!)

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: You are right..that worked! I always tried to change it in the properties and I got the message that I had to drop the table.. thanks

Comment: What Gregorian calendar issues ?

Comment: @TheQuant - Covered here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3310569/513811

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> However I can't just switch the type
>   of the column from datetime to
>   datetime

Sure you can, use `ALTER TABLE TableNAme ALTER column ColumnNAme datetime2`

example

```
USE tempdb
GO

CREATE TABLE Test(SomeDate DATETIME)
INSERT Test values (GETDATE())

SELECT * FROM Test
GO

ALTER TABLE Test ALTER column SomeDate datetime2
GO

INSERT Test values ('16000101')

SELECT * FROM Test
GO
```

Comment: It's not as simple if your column has dependencies, such as indexes and constraints. There is no other way than dropping and re-creating those.

Comment: Having the same challenge here 11 years later. Going for a new column, double maintenance, and then deleting the old one.

Comment: @MarioDS On top of that, I may just now be learning that it doesn't actually *check* for those dependencies before changing it...?