# DateAdd Column caused an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

After executing the following query I am getting an error

> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

I have no idea why this is happening as it worked smoothly for a couple of weeks.  I am just trying to ADD Dates here and compare them to the Start date and End date with a `between` clause.

```
DATEADD(day, -1 , DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,posting_date),0)) BETWEEN start_date and end_date
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can duplicate the error with the following:

```
declare @posting_date datetime
set @posting_date = '1/1/1753'

select DATEADD(day, -1 , DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,@posting_date),0))
```

error after running it:

> Msg 517, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Adding a value to a 'datetime'
>   column caused an overflow.

Basically, posting_date in the above case is the minimum date time value allowed by SQL server.  If you then try to subtract 1 day from it, then it enters an overflow condition.

My guess is that you have a datapoint which is set to [SQL Server's minimum date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server).

Comment: For me `DATEADD(day, -1 , DATEADD(mm, -1753,0))` appears to work, but `DATEADD(day, -1 , DATEADD(mm, -1754,0))` does not.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Well.. the first one should result in the date 11/30/1753, which is a valid SQL server date.  The second one should eval out to 10/31/1753.  Regardless, neither has anything to do with the OP's question

Comment: Oops, I made a typo: it was -1763 and -1764 (with 6, not 5), so his call to `DATEDIFF` returns a negative number less than -1764, meaning that his `posting_date` must be at least 1764 months before 1/1/1900. Good catch.

Comment: THanks guys, Found the error. One record was having 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000 as the Date which was giving the error in the Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN:

> The date argument cannot be incremented to a value outside the range
>   of its data type. In the following statements, the number value that
>   is added to the date value exceeds the range of the date data type.
>   The following error message is returned: "Adding a value to a
>   'datetime' column caused overflow."

What is the data type of the column and the ranges of start_date and end_date?