# Adding x number of years to datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, dateadd

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 150, CAST(dob AS DATETIME)), 107) 
FROM 
    CUSTOMER
```

This code results in the following error:

> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Seems to work fine in sql-server with GETDATE()... Have you checked your data for any anomalies?

Comment: What is the data type for `dob` and show the sample data stored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateAdd Column caused an overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119403/dateadd-column-caused-an-overflow)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 0):

Your `dob` column contains one or more dates that are greater than `Dec 31, 9849` - this is the latest *date* that you can add 150 years to and still remain under the maximum value a DATETIME may have, which is `23:59:59.997` on `Dec 31, 9999`