# Error checking in a web form

Tags: asp.net

Is there somewhere to see examples of error checking.  I have a web form with several controls.  Two of the controls are critical to updating a database and also for the reporting in a gridview.

I am not looking for extremely complex checking, just something to stop the user before the submitting an update to the database.  For example, I have a calendar where the user needs to select a date.  If they fail to select a date, I would like to not process the update and instead return a warning like "Are you nuts, enter a date!"

TIA

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the `RequiredFieldValidator`, among others: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx

Comment: Have you heard about validation controls? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net comes with a set of validation controls you can use to validate the input on the client side before passing it to the server.

In your case, you probably want a **[RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx)**

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbInput" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="tbInput" ValidationGroup="A" ErrorMessage="This is a mandatory field" runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator11" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ValidationGroup="A" Text="Submit"/>
```

Note the usage of `ValidationGroup` and `ControlToValidate` properties

Comment: I also have to compare a drop down list to a login name.  I am capturing the login name using windows authentication when the user selects the web form.  I have a variable stored as @User.  How do I make that work in a compare validator if I don't have a control?  Do I have to put a control out there which is not visible?

Comment: Not sure I understand the exact scenario, but maybe a [HiddenField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) can help

Answer (score 0):

All you need to check is

**Required Field Validator Class**
(This is used when a form is submitted without filling out fields)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx

**Regular Expression Validator Class**
(This is used to check what you have entered is right, for ins, when a phone is provided under email field)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx

**Validation Summary Class**
(Bringing all the error statement messages from the above two classes to the screen. for ins, Email cannot be left empty , Phone number cannot contain alphabets, ...)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the returned value from the control against 'nothing' or whatever the controls default value is.

Something like (pseudocode):

```
if(value is nothing) {
   // print 'Are you nuts? Select a date'
}else{
   // store it in the database
```

If you want more info, please show us some of your code. (edit your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [CustomerValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx), for example:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server"
    ID="DateRangeValidator" 
    ControlToValidate="DateTextBox"
    OnServerValidate="DateRangeValidator_Validate" 
    ErrorMessage="ERROR MESSAGE" />
```

Then implment `DateRangeValidator_Validate` on the server side, adding the relevant date validation logic.

You can also look at the [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx), but that alone won't be enough because that won't stop users [trying to enter dates that can't be inserted into, for example, SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server) - 01/01/1066

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the required field validator: https://web.archive.org/web/20181218053647/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/090200-1.2.shtml
Example:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server"
  id="ValidatorName"
  ControlToValidate="ctrlToValidate"
  ErrorMessage="Message to display for invalid data..."
  display="Dynamic" />
```