# Out of range Datetime Error from C# to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have a C# window application to fill in Date of Birth and send the data to my database with type datetime. Here is the code:

```
DateTime dateOfBirth;
try
{
    dateOfBirth = new DateTime(int.Parse(textBox54.Text), int.Parse(textBox53.Text), int.Parse(textBox52.Text));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
    return;
}
```

It works fine with proper date, but when I randomly test my application and fill in "234" for Year, datetime from varchar conversion out of range error occurs in the statement

```
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How can I catch it? Thanks.

Comment: You also may be interested in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server

Comment: Have you tried wrapping ExecuteNonQuery in a try/catch block?

Comment: Show us the full code.  Where are you passing it to the database / how?

Comment: I pass it with normal sql statement like: insert into MyTable(DateOfBirth) values ('" + DateOfBirth + "')

Comment: Thanks Mixxiphoid, it works.

Comment: Hello @AkariKamigishi before calling DB code, check your date. If it is in correct format then call DB otherwise show error message to user that date is not valid. You can use code given in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.TryParseExact:

**Updated:**

```
    string inputDate = int.Parse(textBox54.Text)+"-"+int.Parse(textBox53.Text)+"-"+int.Parse(textBox52.Text);
    DateTime dateOfBirth ;

    var DateFormat = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate, DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateOfBirth ))
    {

       //Valid Date
      //Call DB here
    }
    else
    {

        // Invalid Date
    }
```

Comment: @Habib you are right. Updated answer. This will first check if inputDate will be valid date then can be use for further processing.

Comment: It still cant catch the error when I input "234" for Year because it's a valid date for C# but not SQL

Comment: @KenClark, the issue here is not parsing the date in C#, its about SQL server throwing exception since date range for both .Net framework and SQL server is different.