# How to convert a date field to a date time format? SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an

> out-of-range value.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

I just need to convert a date field to a date time format.

Comment: Can you post your query which you tried?

Comment: And what is your insert query?

Comment: this looks suspiciously like sql-server as opposed to mysql

Comment: @ Rahul: Its really a long query, but now I discovered where is the error. see my question

Comment: Are you sure the destination type is datetime and not timestamp?

Comment: yes, coz its a temp table which i created and the column type is DATETIME.

Comment: Are you sure this is MySql and not SQL Server? if it's sql server you should probably try to convert your [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) to [DateTime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) and not [DateTime.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

Comment: this is SQL server 2008 RS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of what the code would look like to convert from date to datetime2

```
DECLARE @d1 date;
SET @d1 = GETDATE()

-- When converting date to datetime the minutes portion becomes zero.
SELECT CAST (@d1 AS datetime2) AS [date as datetime2]
```

For more information about cast and convert, see the Microsoft [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You probably get out of range exception because [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) supports a date range between
`January 1, 1 and December 31, 9999` , while [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) supports a date range only between
`January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999`.

Want to know Why 1753? [Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server) (Recommended reading for anyone that likes trivia items)

Try converting to [`Datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) instead of `Datetime`, this should be OK since `Datetime2` supports a date range similar to date.

the conversion can be done simply by using `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST(YourDateTypeColumn As Datetime2)
FROM YourTable
```