# Nullable field cannot accept null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, nullable

Using EF 6. I have an entity (`Person`) that contains a nullable datetime field.

```
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

This made me think I should be able to assign `null` to this property without any issue, like this ...

```
Person.StartDate = null;
```

However, when I get to `context.SaveChanges()` I get an error saying ...

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."

Shouldn't a nullable field be able to accept .... `null`?

Comment: The field is accepting `null` otherwise it would have blown up when it was assigned. It's your database or EF itself that is choking.

Comment: Good point! The error is being thrown when SaveChanges() is called.

Comment: The database field is not nullable, apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your database column nullable too.

Comment: I am using EF Code Migrations so the C# code is generating the database. Shouldn't the database column be nullable already since I defined it as `DateTime?` Do I need to add perhaps a data annotation to the entity? I also looked at the generated schema and the field is listed as able to accept null in the database

Comment: Still worth a double check against the actual database table DDL itself.

Comment: `datetime2` column type can support dates before 1753 while `datetime` can't.  Why is null tripping this?  Not sure.  Why 1753?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server

Comment: @code4life - I agree, worth a check. However, the database shows the field as `StartDate (datetime, null)`

Comment: In general, I hit this error when I'm not using `null` but rather when I'm using `DateTime.Min` or `new Date(1,1,1)`.  Are you sure you're saving `null` and not accidentally initializing it to something else?

Comment: @robrich, How can I set the field as null on database?

Comment: @RafaelGuimarães pop open SQL Management Studio or phpMyAdmin or your DB editor of choice and look at the table definition. There's probably a nullable check-box for this column.

Comment: @robrich In mongodb? on a sql database I know how do it, but in mongodb? nosql...

Comment: @RafaelGuimarães MongoDB has no schema, so I'm really surprised you're getting null errors. Sounds like a `[Required]` attribute on a C# class.

Comment: @robrich  exactly! In doctrine ODM ?