# Garbage value appear in a column instead of default value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a columns called `From_date` and `to_date`. The columns have default constraint as `getdate()` and `9999-12-31` respectively.

But I got something strange after loading data to table.

Instead of default value I am getting value in both the column as `1753-01-01 00:00:00.0000000`

Has anyone came across this situation? How to solve this issue?

Here is some of the table DDL

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [df_FMDT_IX] 
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [from_date] 
GO 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [df_TODT_IX] 
DEFAULT ('9999-12-31') FOR [to_date] 
GO
```

**DATATYPE FOR THE COLUMN IS DATETIME2**

Comment: Perhaps script out your table DDL and post it here including the default constraint. What data type is the column? What happens if you use `CONVERT(DATETIME,'9999-12-31',120)` instead?

Comment: How do you insert your rows? That date value is probably some default in the framework/language you use

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: datatype of column is datetime2.                    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [df_FMDT_IX]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [from_date]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [df_TODT_IX]  DEFAULT ('9999-12-31') FOR [to_date]
GO
Thanks

Comment: @PeterHenell: i am using import-export sql wizard to load table from flat file. format: tab delimited

Comment: So have you established whether that value is from the `default` or from the datafile? Why wouldn't you do that as your very first thing?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: shall i drop table and re-create it with these check?

Comment: Yes. but **first** establish whether these values are from the default or from data values in the file. In fact drop the constraints altogether and load the file and see if you still get the values. Sounds like it's not the constraint at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That date you're seeing is the minimum date value in SQL.

[What is the significance of 1/1/1753 in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server)

I'm assuming someone's entered a zero in that column which will display as the min possible value.

Comment: i am loading data from flatfile to sql table using import-export wizard. both the column in the flat file are blank so default value should be there, but instead of default some garbage value appearing in the column.

Comment: When you say blank, is that a zero length string? it's not the same as a NULL value.

Comment: Then it'll use that zero length string as the data to insert, that's not the same as inserting a NULL value and then using the default value. You'd have to put some sort of error capture to see if the data you're trying to import is a string with a length of less than 1 and replace this with a proper NULL value.

Comment: is it possible by constraint on the column. please suggest.

Comment: Well, the issue isn't with your constraint, it's with the data import process. You could look to see whether you can edit the data in your import step. Alternatively, the messy approach would be to run an update statement after you've done the import to update these values.

Comment: You could just not import these columns if they're always the default values.