# Access ODBC returning incorrect dates prior to the year 1753

Tags: r, date, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2016

I have a strange problem when using R ODBC to connect to an Access 2016 database.

The dates in R have a difference of -28 days by reference to the dates from the Access database.

For example, in Access: 1639-01-24; in R: 1638-12-27. The format of the date in R is "1638-12-27 LMT".

To solve this problem I had to get date variables as string with the `Format` function:

```
Select format([date],'yyyy-mm-dd') ...
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Could this be related to the Gregorian calendar? Difference is too large. What happens with more recent dates (ie 20th Century)

Comment: I think you are right! I've checked with a more recent date and it's correct.

Comment: But for 17th century and 18th century there are errors but with variations: 16 days from 1686; 6 days for 1732. It's very strange.

Comment: It must be something else. The Gregorian calendar was introduced back in 1582 and the shift from the Julian calendar was "only" 10 days. However, many countries adopted the calendar much later, some for less than 100 years ago. Still, that cannot explain 28 days. Also, note that the Access (VBA) calendar implementation is a _"pseudo" Gregorian_ calendar as it happily moves back from the introduction at 1582-10-15 to 100-01-01. Thus, `DateAdd("m", -1, #1582/10/15#)` returns _1582-09-15_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the `Date/Time` field type in Access being defined as a "date or time value between the years 100 and 9999" ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208866(v=office.12).aspx)), the Access ODBC driver appears to have problems dealing with dates prior to January 1, 1753. I was able to confirm that using the `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` under both RODBC and .NET System.Data.Odbc.

`1753-01-01` in Access is returned by Access ODBC as `1753-01-01` (correct), but
`1752-12-31` in Access is returned by Access ODBC as `1752-12-30` (wrong)

and, as you have found, the discrepancy becomes larger as we go further back in time.

There is also a Microsoft Knowledge Base article [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/252699) related to problems with Access ODBC when trying to insert dates prior to 1753.

It is probably not a coincidence that 1753-01-01 is the earliest possible date for the `DATETIME` column type in SQL Server. For more details on the significance of that date, see

[What is the significance of 1/1/1753 in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3310569/2144390)

There is only one `Date/Time` type in Access so we can't convert the value to something like `DATETIME2` in SQL Server. Therefore the best workaround is probably to use `Format()` to convert the date value to text as mentioned in the question.

It is also worth noting that the Access OLEDB provider (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) does not exhibit the same problems with dates prior to 1753.