# SQL Server 2012 ISDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server

The MS doc states that `ISDATE()`

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, **or** datetime value; otherwise, 0

So why is it returning `0` in the example below?

```
DECLARE @DT VARCHAR(30) = '1/4/1752'

SELECT 
    ISDATE(@DT),
    TRY_CONVERT(DATE, @DT, 101),
    TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @DT),
    TRY_CAST(@DT as DATE),  
    TRY_CAST(@DT AS DATETIME)
```

returns

```
0   1752-01-04  NULL    1752-01-04  NULL
```

Change the date to 1753 and ...

```
1   1753-01-04  1753-01-04 00:00:00.000 1753-01-04  1753-01-04 00:00:00.000

select ISDATE('17521231'), ISDATE('17530101') gives

0   1
```

Comment: Note that `17520401` *is* a valid `DATETIME2` value, but *not* a valid `DATETIME` value, so `ISDATE` still returns 0. The `TRY_CONVERT` approach as suggested by Gordon will cover this case correctly too. (And the documentation probably needs tweaking -- `17520401` is a valid `DATE`, but not, apparently, "a valid date value", which is wrong.) The behavior of `ISDATE` itself likely will not be changed due to backwards compatibility concerns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3310588/2975396

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate ,documentation states `range for datetime data is 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31, while the range for date data is 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31.` and it returns `Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0.`

Comment: I suggest opening an issue on Microsoft Connect for this, asking them to either change the behavior of `ISDATE` or amend the documentation to make it clear that `ISDATE` does not cover the extended range of `DATE`.

Comment: @Jeroen, thanks for reading the question. It will just remain one of those anomalies!

Answer (score 13):

As explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx), the earliest `datetime` value is '1753-01-01'.

I would suggest that you use `try_convert()` instead.  This gives you more flexibility:

```
 try_convert(date, '17521231') is not null
```

The `date` data type goes back to year one.

Comment: The documentation also explains that the earliest date is "while the range for date data is 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31" ans ISDATE() doc says "Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0." so surely ISATE('17520101') is a valid date?

Comment: there wasn't a year zero!