# SQL Server - Integers being used as Dates

Tags: sql-server

I have been using SQL for a little while now - having to use Oracle and SQL Server for my work - however, I have just come across something I have not seen before.

After seeing this and doing a bit of research it is said that, in SQL server, the number `0` can be used as the base date, which is:

> 1900-01-01

so for example: 
`select DATEDIFF(yy, 0, '2017-12-31')` would return `117`, as `1900-01-01` substitutes the `0`.

My first question is, why is this, considering this is not the minimum date value in SQL (which is the year 1753 I believe)?

My second question is that I came across another piece of SQL which uses the number `-1` instead of `0`.

After some testing, I can assume that it is referring to `1899-12-31`. but i cannot be sure as I cannot find anything on this number being used as a date anywhere online. Am I correct?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Pac0 Actually it depends on the data type you are using. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql#DateandTimeDataTypes

Comment: @Pred okay this is assuming the datatype is a `date`.

Comment: A more interesting question is [why 1753?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server)

Comment: @ZoharPeled honestly, i wanted to ask this question as well but i thought it might be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Well, then, read the answers in the link. It's both educating and entertaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is little reason to use `0` as a date.  The primary reason (originally) was to truncate the time component:

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, <datetime>), 0)
```

Note that this would work with any date value, but `0` tended to be used.

This is now done using `select cast(<datetime> as date)`.

But to answer your question.  SQL Server does support negative numbers as dates.  The reason for using "-1" is for compatibility with Excel.  In Excel the "0" date is "1900-01-00" which is effectively "1899-12-31".

I'm not sure why Microsoft software has two different zero values for dates.  (Well, I do . . . Microsoft historically acquired software rather than write it itself.)  It is a little confusing, but that is probably why "-1" is being used.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, in SQL Server, the date `0` represents 01 January 1900.

```
0 = 19000101
1 = 19000102
2 = 19000103
...
43080 = 20171212
```

Unsurprisingly, therefore, numbers below zero work the same way:

```
-1 = 18991231
-2 = 18991230
...
-53690 = 17530101
```

As for why 0 is 1900, this likely dates back to prior to SQL Server, when it was called SyBase. Most likely, back then, 0 represented 19000101, and as SyBase become SQL Server, it was prudent to keep the the same process (as otherwise it could well break people's existing code).