# How to not display Value of datetime if contains format/value like (1753-01-01) - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

Im showing `Warrenty_Expires` of product in my view , but sometimes Warrenty_Expires contains value exactly like this `1753-01-01 00:00:00.000` and i want to say if `Warrenty_Expires` contains this value should not display it  in my view.Can anyone please help me  or point me into the right direction :)

This is i end up with but its not working and still showing this value (1753-01-01).

View:

```
  if (Field.WarrentyExpiress.HasValue) //Check for null value
 {
          //Check if Warrenty contains this value(1753-01-01)

         if (Field.WarrentyExpiress.Value.ToString().Contains("1753-01-01"))
          {
           <td>Not available</td>

          }

         else
          {
             <td>@Field.WarrentyExpiress.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>

          }

 }

else
 {
   <td>Not available</td>
 }
```

Model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Warrenty_Expires { get; set; }
```

ViewModel:

```
public DateTime? WarrentyExpiress { get; set; }
```

Comment: If specified year, month and day is bothering you, I think you can just check DateTime.Year, DateTime.Month and DateTime.Day

Comment: `If (Field.WarrentyExpiress.Value == new DateTime(1753, 1, 1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess around with string representations of `DateTime`, simply compare against another instance of the `DateTime` struct:

```
if (Field.WarrentyExpiress.Value == new DateTime(1753, 1, 1).Date)
{
    <td>Not available</td>
}
```

BTW, an interesting read: [Why 1753?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

What if you want to use multilingual? I would use the Date property of the DateTime.

```
if (Field.WarrentyExpiress.Value.Date == new DateTime(1753,1,1))
{
    ....
}
```

Never compare `ToString()` when something is regional dependend.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that the year 1753 would be anything but this special case, so you could even do:

```
if (Field.WarrentyExpiress.Value.Year == 1753)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to do this via string processing. String is just about the 2nd worst format you could work with.

Figure out the actuall value of [DateTime.Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2) that `1753-01-01 00:00:00.000` represents. DateTime just stores the amount of ticks since 1st January 0001 00:00:00.000. Every other value - the day, the month, the year, the string representation - are just a interpretation of that Tick value.

Once you know what the tick count is, you can check for anything less or equal to that count and filter it out.