# Why does creating a date older than 1 Jan 1753 from a string in TSQL throw conversion error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2019 I run the following code without error:

```
declare @d1 as datetime;
set @d1 = cast('1 Jan 1753 00:00am' as datetime);
select @d1 'date';
```

But when I run this code it fails:

```
declare @d1 as datetime;
set @d1 = cast('1 Jan 1752 00:00am' as datetime);
select @d1 'date';
```

Giving the error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The only difference is the first one is 1 Jan 1753, and the second is 1 Jan 1752.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server

Comment: As of SQL Server **2008**, I'd recommend ditching `DATETIME` due to its various limitations (like not supporting dates before 1753) - use `DATE` if you need date only (not time portion), or `DATETIME2(n)` if you need the time, too

Comment: @marc_s, it appears you can't subtract with DATETIME2:
Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator.

Comment: You should use **proper** method - like `DATEADD(....)` - not just subtract an  `INT` from a date - what does that really mean?? What are you subtracting? Seconds? Minutes? Hours? Days? Years? Thank **goodness** that's no longer supported !!

Comment: @marc_s, I was doing the following to get the hours between two dates: declare @v1 as DATETIME;`
declare @v2 as DATETIME;
set @v1 = cast('1 Jan 2021 00:00am' as DATETIME);
set @v2 = cast('2 Jan 2021 5:01am' as DATETIME);
select cast( @v2 - @v1 as float) * 24; ` I was doing this because DATEDIFF_BIG was thrown an error that the number was to big when the dates were to far apart.  How can I do this with a DATETIME2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue?view=net-5.0#:%7E:text=The%20minimum%20valid%20date%20for%20a,SqlDateTime%20structure%20is%20January%201%2C%201753.), the minimum date for a `DATETIME` column is 1/1/1753.  Use `DATE` instead. It can go all the way back to 1/1/1.