# Why does arithmetic on `Temporal.Duration` instances require a `relativeTo` reference calendar date?

Tags: javascript, datetime, calendar, duration, ecmascript-temporal

The proposed JavaScript Temporal date/time API casually mentions “Interpreting years, months, or weeks requires a reference point” ([source](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/duration.html#total)), but I fail to understand what is meant by this.

More specifically, the following is not possible:

```js
let oneWeek = Temporal.Duration.from({ weeks: 1 });
console.log(`one week is ${oneWeek.total('day')} days`);
```

It will result in the following error:

```
RangeError: a starting point is required for balancing calendar units
```

This can be resolved by bloating my code with a `relativeTo` parameter to the `total()` call, as follows:

```js
console.log(`one week is ${oneWeek.total({ unit: 'day', relativeTo: Temporal.Now.plainDateISO() })} days`);
```

But could anyone elaborate on *why* this is necessary? As far as I can tell a week has always been and will always be seven days…?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as I can tell a week has always been and will always be seven days

Even around a [daylight saving time](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) change?
You know, those Sundays where you change the clock back or forward by one hour?
If you measure a duration from, say, Wednesday to the next Wednesday, then this “one week” could be exactly 7 days long, or 6 days and 23 hours, or 7 days and 1 hour.

See the documentation on [Balancing Relative to a Reference Point](//tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/balancing.html#balancing-relative-to-a-reference-point):

> Balancing that includes days, weeks, months, and years is more complicated because those units can be different lengths.
> In the default ISO calendar, a year can be 365 or 366 days, and a month can be 28, 29, 30, or 31 days.
> In other calendars, years aren’t always 12 months long and weeks aren’t always 7 days.
> Finally, in time zones that use Daylight Saving Time (DST) days are not always 24 hours long.

This is also referring to [leap years](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).

There’s also [discussion in issue #857](//github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/issues/857):

> Specifically, the following time scale unit conversions are contextual (the “conversion boundaries”):
>
> - year ↔ day (365, 366 days)
> - month ↔ day (28, 29, 30, 31 days)
> - minute ↔ second (59, 60, 61 seconds)

That last one is referring to [leap seconds](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

And of course, the Temporal API has to account for what happened in [September, 1752](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3310569/4642212).
Related: [Get number of days in a specific month that are in a date range](/a/53089628/4642212).

The point is that the answer to the question of how long some unit of time is, will change depending on context.
This isn’t just about time zones; different calendars have all sorts of anomalies.

Sure, the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) used in browsers might not be affected by the year 1752, but that requires knowledge about *which calendar to use*.
You supply this information with `relativeTo`; it’s contained within `Temporal.Now.plainDateISO()`.
Now it’s clear that an ISO week can be used which will always have 7 days.
But without this information, it’s impossible to tell exactly, and a *general* date and time API cannot be *sure* that an ISO week is what you actually meant.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I would still argue that a week has always seven days (unless perhaps we explicitly reference September 1752 or something like that), but I guess this is up for debate then.

Comment: The Gregorian calendar in use in browsers is "proleptic" meaning it is extended backwards indefinitely, so the Julian-Gregorian change date isn't a problem here.

Comment: A week always has seven days _in the ISO 8601 calendar_, but not necessarily in other calendars. You supply a calendar with the relativeTo parameter.

Comment: @ptomato I’ve addressed your concerns in an edit, thank you! Yes, the fact that `Temporal.Now.plainDateISO()` contains the calendar to use is a very important detail that I forgot to mention. This should be clear now.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the word _proleptic_ to my vocabulary