# Excel VBA - Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error when assigning a Date

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I am trying to assign a Date to a table column. I get 1004 error on each Date column.

```
Public Type JobStatusDetailLine
    ...

    PromisedShipDate As Date
    LastOpDate As Date
    ShipDate As Date
    
End Type

Public JobStatusDetailArr() As JobStatusDetailLine
```

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(JobStatusDetailArr)
        Dim newLabRow As ListRow
        Set newLabRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
        With newLabRow
            
            .Range(1) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).SalesGroup
            .Range(2) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).BuildLocation
            .Range(3) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).ProjectManager
            .Range(4) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).Customer
            .Range(5) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).JobNum
            .Range(6) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).AssemblySeq
            .Range(7) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).PartNum
            .Range(8) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).PartDesc
            .Range(9) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).ProdQuantity
            .Range(10) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).JobReleased
            .Range(11) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).PromisedShipDate
            .Range(12) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).LastOpDate
            .Range(13) = JobStatusDetailArr(i).ShipDate
                       
          
        End With
        
    Next i
```

Error occurs on Columns 11, 12 and 13. Do I need to do something specific to assign a date? I am sure I have done this in the past with no problem.

Comment: how/where redim JobStatusDetailArr() ?  what is value of (i) ?    More complete code is needed for someone to help you

Comment: See if error occurs with `.Range(11) = Date`

Comment: I have added the complete For Loop in the example.

Comment: Runs fine with `.Range(11) = Date `. The date comes from SqlServer query `JobStatusDetailArr(i).PromisedShipDate = adoDbRs("PromisedShipDate")`

Comment: Do you know what the value of JobStatusDetailArr(i).PromisedShipDate is when the error occurs ?

Comment: I just noticed it fails on 01/01/1753. If I keep jumping over that line until I get a different date, then it works.  I know it is the value of `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue` which I am using if I encounter a NULL date field. Is this a bad date in Excel or something?

Comment: Do you want to see the date as 01/01/1753 or as blank. ?

Comment: Try formatting the date `.Range(11) = Format(JobStatusDetailArr(i).PromisedShipDate,"dd-mm-yyyy")`, or test for the year `If Year(JobStatusDetailArr(i).PromisedShipDate) < 1900 then`

Comment: Thanks. I eventually removed setting NULL dates to SqlDateTime.MinValue and just displayed them as blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel stores dates as numbers, 1.0 representing the first second of January 1, 1900. Although a date variable can hold a date before then, there is a problem displaying it unless you specify the format. Since you have multiple dates to check then use a function to check if the date is [01/01/1753](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server) your replacement for NULL.

```vb
Function IsDateNull(dt As Date)
    If Year(dt) > 1753 Then IsDateNull = Format(dt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End Function
```

also you could assign the array element to an intermediate variable.

```vb
Sub Demo()

    Dim i As Long, j As JobStatusDetailLine
    Dim tbl As ListObject, newLabRow As ListRow
    
    Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(JobStatusDetailArr)
        j = JobStatusDetailArr(i)
        Set newLabRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
        With newLabRow
            .Range(1) = j.SalesGroup
            .Range(2) = j.BuildLocation
            .Range(3) = j.ProjectManager
            .Range(4) = j.Customer
            .Range(5) = j.JobNum
            .Range(6) = j.AssemblySeq
            .Range(7) = j.PartNum
            .Range(8) = j.PartDesc
            .Range(9) = j.ProdQuantity
            .Range(10) = j.JobReleased
            .Range(11) = IsDateNull(j.PromisedShipDate)
            .Range(12) = IsDateNull(j.LastOpDate)
            .Range(13) = IsDateNull(j.ShipDate)
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```