# How best to represent *very* wide time ranges?

Tags: date, datetime, rust, biginteger

I'm wanting to write a program to store various events across all of history, from the big bang until the heat death of the universe.

Is there a standard way of representing this range of time? Most datetime libraries struggle with dates more than 5000 years in the future/past, so I don't think any existing libraries will work, except maybe as a default for "close enough" datetimes.

I'm happy if it's not exact, and if I can avoid it I won't consider the different calendars. Especially for events that occurred millions of years ago, I don't need millisecond precision.

I'll be writing this in Rust, but the implementation shouldn't change too much from one language to the next.

My first thought would be to wrap a datetime library with my own struct that defines some 64-bit integers for the greater time ranges:

```rs
struct BigTime {
    datetime: <library's datetime object>,
    millions_of_years: i64,
    trillions_of_years: i64,
}
```

Is there a "neater" way of doing this?

Comment: As far as asking for a library-recommendation, that question is outside the scope of  SO, so I recommend removing that part of the question. As a general solution I'd strongly advise to abandon all hope: Calendars, especially those that are concerned with "deep time" are [incredibly complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server) and of very little practical use. It's probably easiest to cook-up a 128-bit-seconds representation ("stardate") since the big-bang and convert standard datetime-representations into that, but never back.

Comment: As an added side-note: If you are really concerned about *very* deep time, it's probably best to do away with linear time alltogether and use a cosmological representation like the Robertson Walker scale factor. Otherwise 1-unit very close to the big-bang is completely different from 1-unit in the year 3231AD.

Comment: My intuition would be to use 64-bit floating-point seconds, which would have sub 1-hour precision at the point of the big bang (if my napkin math is correct).

Comment: The heat death of the universe is in about 10^100 years, so 64 bits (or 128 bits for that matter) aren't gonna cut it I'm afraid

Comment: @beyarkay 64-bit floating-point numbers can express 10^308, which in seconds far surpasses 10^100 years.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb, but won't I run into precision issues when I'm trying to represent datetimes that are far from the epoch but close to each other?

Comment: @beyarkay yes, it could have this problem (depending on what you mean by "close to each other") since floating-point numbers have fixed *precision* regardless of the scale. But you also said you *"don't need millisecond precision [..] for events that occurred millions of years ago"*. So how much precision do you need?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure about the exact precision (I'm making a timeline so don't know exactly what will go into the timeline) but it's possible that 64-bit floats will be enough. I guess I'll have to implement it and see how (in)accurate things get